# How to change fancybox width?

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

I have a gallery width 1920 width and long height, but fancybox show my images with fit width and height to the screen, I want to fit my image to screen width with height scrolling, here is my codes:

```
$.fancybox.open(attemp2.map(function (el) {
    return {
        src: el,
        opts: {
            caption: tempName,
        }
    };
}), {
    loop: false,
    toolbar: true
});
```

Comment: Can u share jsfiddle or snippet?

Comment: There is currently no option for that, but it is planned, see https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1343

Answer (score 1):

Here a little code snippet from my own usage of fancybox.
I adjusted width and height by percentage.

```
$(".imagebox").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 600,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    wrapCSS     : 'fancy-imagebox', // add a class selector to the fancybox wrap
    margin      : [0, 0, 0, 0],
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '90%',
    autoSize    : true
});
```

Comment: Your example is for fancy box old versions, I am using version 3